# Las Vegas Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

In some notes i'm reading it says that the definition of a Las Vegas Algorithm is

An algorithm which always outputs the correct answer but has unbounded running time, with the expected running time required to be bounded. It says as an exercise (equivalently) we require the running to be bounded but allow the algorithm to output a special answer '?' so that the probability of outputting '?' is $\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

I faily to see exactly why these are equivalent. I can see that we can turn any Las Vegas algorithm into the the one stated as being equivalent as follows

If $X$ is the random variable representing the running time then using Markov's inequality $\mathbb{P}(X \geq C) \leq \mathbb{E}(X)/C$ so we can pick $C$ large enough to ensure this is less than $1/2$. Then if the running time goes above $C$ the algorithm outputs '?'.

How do we show any algorithm which halts in finite time but can output '?' with probability $1/2$ is equivalent to a Las Vegas Algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the algorithm repeatedly (and independently) until you don't get '?'.

Comment: Ok i think i'm getting slightly confused. Why would the algorithm not necessarily output '?'. Can you give an example of such an algorithm and what it does. The reason for my confusion is i'm viewing it as follows. On some inputs the algorithm will never be able to run quicker than $C$ and so will always output '?'.

Comment: Each time you run it (on a given input), independently of what has happened before, the algorithm will have probability $\ge 1/2$ of finishing with an output other than '?'.  So with probability 1 it will eventually do this.  If on some input the algorithm always outputs '?', it doesn't satisfy your assumption.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense